# Kinect v1 integrates with qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opengl, kinect

I have been working with Qt and Kinect v1 for couple of weeks. I don't know how to create a screen inside a Qt GUI and show stream video captured by Kinect.

I have searched for a in-depth tutorial in the Internet but it seems like nothing related directly to my problem.

I prefer programming in C++, using Qt 5.6. I know how to use some basic Qt feature but have never experienced with OpenGL in qt before. I can also run Kinect using Developer Toolkit browser and it works perfectly. Then I saw a tutorial using kinect and C++ at the link: https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~edzhang/tutorials/kinect/kinect2.html. 
I followed the instructions and I can create a new windows show the stream video captured by Kinect sensor but when I using the same code in the Qt project, it just only show a black video. I don't know how to resolve the problem at all. The code is too long because I write it in the project created last week.

Comment: I removed your request for tutorial, because such requests are explicitly off-topic here (for better or for worse). Anyway, you should try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because without one it will be very hard to help you...

Comment: Anyway, at a glance, you could maybe get started by trying to 1) create a Qt app which shows `QImage` in a label (no Kinect yet), 2) Make the image animated (by just drawing random lines and refreshing display, no Kinect yet), 3) Change the animated `QImage` display to show Kinect data instead of your random lines.